# Richtige Kommasetzung bei "..., oder, falls nicht, ..." oder doch "..., oder falls nicht, ..."

Tags: comma

Bei folgendem Satz würde mich mal die richtige Kommasetzung interessieren. Ist die Kommasetzung hier richtig:

"Haben Sie eventuell bereits eine Vorlage dafür, oder, falls nicht, könnten Sie bitte eine erstellen und sie mir schicken?"

oder hier:

"Haben Sie eventuell bereits eine Vorlage dafür, oder falls nicht, könnten Sie bitte eine erstellen und sie mir schicken?"

Comment: Hast du schon irgend welche eigenen Erkundungen im Reich des Internets oder der gedruckten Bücherwelt unternommen?

Comment: Ja, klar @Olafant, nix gefunden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mit "falls" nutzt du eine konditionale Satzverbindung, die - wie der Name sagt - zwei Sätze miteinander verbindet.

> Bei der konditionalen Satzverbindung werden zwei Sätze verbunden, bei denen ein Satz eine „Bedingung“ beschreibt, unter der eine „Folge“ eintreten kann.

Bei der Verbindung zweier Sätze werden beide fast immer mit Komma getrennt - auch die konditionale Satzverbindung ist hier keine Aussnahme. In deinem Beispiel verkürzt du einen der beiden Sätze.

Statt

> *"falls Sie keine Vorlage dafür haben"*

schreibst du

> *"falls nicht"*

Das spielt meiner Meinung nach bei der Beurteilung der Komma-Setzung keine Rolle - auch ein so (umgangssprachlich) abgekürtzter Satz bleibt grammatikalisch ein Satz.

Darauf basierend gehe ich fest davon aus, das folgende Komma-Setzung korrekt ist:

> *Haben Sie eventuell bereits eine Vorlage dafür, oder, falls nicht, könnten Sie bitte eine erstellen und sie mir schicken?*

Quelle: https://deutschegrammatik20.de/komplexer-satz/ubersicht-satzverbindung/satzverbindung-wenn/

Da dies in deutsch meiner Meinung nach sehr holprig aussieht, ersetze ich solche Fälle gern mit Gedankenstrich statt Komma (also *"... eine Vorlage dafür, oder – falls nicht – könnten Sie bitte ..."*). Aber das nur am Rande.

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis, dass das ein umgangssprachlich abgekürzter Satz ist.